# Checking the Tags of each TextBox in an array

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, string-interning

How do I check the Tag property of all the TextBox controls in an array?
I want something like this:

```
If textBox.Tag And textbox2.Tag And textbox21.Tag And
   textbox22.Tag And textbox23.Tag And textbox24.Tag = "2" Then
```

This is my array of TextBoxes:

```
Dim allTextboxes() As TextBox = {textBox, narNaslov, narPersona, narDani, narPersona2,
                                 kupIme, kupAdresa, kupKontakt, uvBroj, uvDatum, uvIznos,
                                 uvAvans, uvRok, uvNacin, datumTbox}
```

Comment: Create a basic loop and check the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the LINQ [`All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_All__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)-Method

```
If allTextBoxes.All(Function(t) t.Tag.ToString = "2") Then
    'All Tags are "2"
End If
```

---

To avoid a [`NullReferenceException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), if one of the textboxes is `Nothing` you can add an additional check:

```
If allTextBoxes.All(Function(t) t IsNot Nothing AndAlso t.Tag.ToString = "2") Then
    'All Tags are "2"
End If
```

Or you can use the [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (Visual Basic v. 14 or greater)

```
If allTextBoxes.All(Function(t) t?.Tag.ToString = "2") Then
    'All Tags are "2"
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the LINQ's [All()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all) extension method to verify whether **all** the Controls in the array have the same Tag.
You could use the [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) method to verify whether **at least one** of the Controls in the array has its `Tag` set to the specified value.

If you have **`Option Strict ON`**, to avoid a `NullReferenceException`, since the `Tag` property is of type `Object` and can be null (`Nothing`), you can use the [Is operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/is-operator) to perform the check:
(a Control in the array could be `nothing`, too, at some point, so we could use `txt?.Tag Is (...)`.
In this case, even when one of TextBoxes is `Nothing` for some reason, if the other TextBoxes all have the same `Tag` value, the method will return `True`)

```
Dim result As Boolean = allTextboxes.All(Function(txt) txt?.Tag Is "2")
```

If `result` is `True` then all the `TextBoxes.Tag` property is set to the value used in the comparison.

This comparison will return True when:

- The string is assigned using the Property Grid in the Designer
- In code, with a direct value assignment: `Control.Tag = "2"`,
- In code, using a Field or a Local variable:

  ```
    Private TagValue As String = "2" 
    [Control].Tag = TagValue

    [Control]?.Tag Is "2"       => True
    [Control]?.Tag Is TagValue  => True
  ```

As noted by [Visual Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867555/checking-tags-for-each-textbox-in-array/53867854?noredirect=1#comment94583399_53867854), the `Is operator` doesn't perform a value comparison; it determines whether two Objects refer to the same Object (in this case, the string is created programmatically, so the comparison is performed on the string reference in the [intern pool table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern)).
This could be a desired outcome or it may be not.

Setting:

```
Dim TagValue As String = New String("2"c, 1) 
[Control].Tag = TagValue 
   
[Control].Tag Is "2"           => False
[Control].Tag Is TagValue      => True

[Control].Tag.Equals("2")      => True
[Control].Tag.Equals(TagValue) => True
```

If/when a strict value comparison is required, the previous method can be changed in:

```
Dim result As Boolean = allTextboxes.All(Function(txt) txt.Tag.Equals("2")
```

It will return `True` in both cases: the `Tag` value is compared to determine if the two objects are equal.
It will also be `True`, in this case, even if one or more of the Controls in the array is/are disposed of or otherwise `null` and it's **`Option Strict`**-compliant.

However, a `NullReferenceException` will be raised if one of the `Tag` properties is set to `Nothing`.
In this case a double check is required:

```
Dim result As Boolean = allTextboxes.
    All(Function(txt) txt.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso txt.Tag.Equals("2"))
```

Comment: Nice answer, but note that `Is` checks for object reference and thus may return `False` if the string in `Tag` is not interned (even though it consists of the same characters as the one you compare with).

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Well, it will work when the value is set in the designer, by code with a direct assignment: `Control.Tag = "2"`, by a *value string*: `Private TagValue As String = "2"` then `Control.Tag = TagValue` or `Control.Tag = "2"` will be `True`. But it's of course correct that if `Dim TagValue As String = New String("2"c, 1) Control.Tag = TagValue` then `Control.Tag = "2"` will be `False`, while `Control.Tag = TagValue` will be `True`. I'll make a note.

Comment: Yes, because when you set the `Tag` property through the designer or using _that specific_ variable of yours you're giving it a constant string. All constant strings are automatically interned at (JIT-)compile time. But if the OP were to fetch or parse the string from somewhere, it would no longer work unless he/she makes sure to call [`String.Intern()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=netframework-4.7.2) before checking it (which is something you might not want to do for every string :).