# Comparing strings in a loop using Is Operator

Tags: vb.net

`Is` **Operator** works fine when comparing two strings like:

```
Dim str1 As String = "TagnameX"
Dim str2 As String = "TagnameX"

Dim strChk as boolean = str1 Is str2
'strChk returns True
```

But when one of the strings is extracted by `Substring` it returns false ! as below:

```
Dim str1 As String = "t#1TagnameX"
Dim str1Extract As String = str1.Substring(3, 8)
Dim strArr() = {"Tagname1", "Tagname2", "TagnameX"}  

 For i = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
      If strArr(i) Is str1Extract Then
         MsgBox("TagnameX found!")
      else
         MsgBox("TagnameX was not found!")
      End If
 Next
'TagnameX was not found!
```

so am i using it wrong in some how? thanks for your help! :)

Comment: A few notes on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53867854/7444103)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Is-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/is-operator) returns whether two references are equal: that is, whether the two variables refer to the same location in memory.

The first code snippet returns `True` because for literal strings, .NET [interns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509035/why-only-literal-strings-saved-in-the-intern-pool-by-default) duplicates rather than keeping separate identical copies in memory, so `str1` and `str2` refer to the same string in memory.

The second code snippet returns `False` because .NET does not necessarily intern intermediate strings, such as strings returned by `Substring`. So the variables `str` and `strExtract` do not refer to the same string.

You should use the equals operator `=` to compare the value of two strings.

Comment: Thank you for the information! i was just intersted of using Is operator in the comparison!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the `Is` operator does what you think it does.

> The Is operator determines if two object references refer to the same object. However, it does not perform value comparisons.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/is-operator

Instead just use `=` to compare string values.

```
If strArr(i) = str1Extract Then
```

Comment: Although what you said normally makes sense, the `String` `Is` operator has been redefined to compare values, so OP's example makes sense. The redefinition probably just doesn't hold in some specific cases.

Comment: @laancelot interesting. The docs didn't mention specific behaviour for strings. Do you have some resource about that?

Comment: @PhilippGrathwohl I should have linked it while I had it, and I can't put my hand on it today. I'll update you if I find it again.

Comment: @PhilippGrathwohl Still can't find my source, but nevermind anyway. Experimenting showed that the `Is` _does_ compare references. At initialization, string variables with the same value will point toward the same memory cells. [You can "fool" the compiler by concatenating strings and avoid this comportment](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B10ox9). I admit I prefer this to the alternative.